# Message pops up on booting ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: 16.04, bash

```
Error found when loading /home/user/.profile
/home/user/.profile line 20: command not found
As a result the session will not be configured correctly 
Fix the problem as soon as feasible
```

This is the output of `cat -n /home/user/.profile`:

```
 1  # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
 2  # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
 3  # exists.
 4  # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
 5  # the files are located in the bash-doc package.
 6  
 7  # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
 8  # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
 9  #umask 022
10  
11  # if running bash
12  if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
13      # include .bashrc if it exists
14      if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
15      . "$HOME/.bashrc"
16      fi
17  fi
18  
19  # set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
20  if [ -d "$HOME/bin"] ; then
21      PATH="$HOME/BIN:$PATH"
22  fi
23  
24  #Make JAVA_HOME first...
25  export JAVA_HOME=/home/yashkanna/.javajre/jre1.8.0_161
26  PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

There is a space missing between `"$HOME/bin"` and `]` in line 20, on Line 21 it should be `"$HOME/bin"`.

Replace

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin"] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/BIN:$PATH"
fi
```

with

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```